# Change what file an Outlook attachment points to

Tags: c#, email, outlook, email-attachments, outlook-2010

For instance, I have a word document as an Outlook attachment. I want to have a C# program that will find that file's local location, process it into a PDF, and then change the email's attachment to that new PDF file. The next time that attachment is opened, it will open the PDF and not the word document.

Edit 1: The email attachment is in my inbox, as someone has sent this file to me. I am able to edit the actual word file just like any other document just fine. I figure this would be possible by adding

Is this function possible? and remoreceived chments to existing recieved emails as well.

Comment: Is this before sending? Or in the inbox? Can you talk us through why you want to do this?  Also please provide a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: This might be helpful  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/modify-an-attachment-of-an-outlook-email-message     this would be easier as an outlook addin rather than via interop.

Comment: thanks penguinswin3! what happens next? re https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29331/in-danganronpa-how-can-a-classroom-trial-be-called-if-there-are-only-2-witnesse and https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29330/in-danganronpa-what-happens-in-a-drawn-vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. You can develop an Outlook COM add-in (for example, a VSTO based one). The `Attachment` class provides the [SaveAsFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/attachment-saveasfile-method-outlook) method which saves the attachment to the specified path. Then you can automate Word where you may open the file just saved and re-save it using the .pdf file format. Or you may consider using third-party components that don't require Word installed on the system. After converting the document and getting the required pdf file you may remove an old attachment and re-add a new one. The [Attachments.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachments.add.aspx) creates a new attachment in the Attachments collection.

You may find the following articles helpful:

- [Attach a File to a Mail Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/attach-a-file-to-a-mail-item?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Modify an Attachment of an Outlook Email Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/modify-an-attachment-of-an-outlook-email-message)
- [How To: Add an attachment to an Outlook e-mail message](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/10/how-to-add-attachment-to-e-mail-message/)